# How to find specific string by regex preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get the link by applying preg_match in php here is my code

```
$string = playlist: [{
        image: "http://77.81.98.55/i/01/00012/d6ntku2p3tnn.jpg",
        provider: "http://static.vidzi.tv/nplayer/vidzi.swf",
        sources: [{
            file: "http://vidzi.tv/6c90fqha0k9i-4b4a926f75863405c12bfaeb331b331c.m3u8?embed=",
            type: 'hls'
        },{
        file: "http://77.81.98.55/gzuqiu4h342qedz7nknr5h3sli74im5vv7f2ae7z2pxjxhqnqxk4625rsdpq/v.mp4"
        }]
        ,tracks: [{file: "http://vidzi.tv/6c90fqha0k9i-4b4a926f75863405c12bfaeb331b331c.vtt", kind: "thumbnails"}]
    }]

preg_match('/file: "(.*?)",/i', $result, $dl_link);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dl_link);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => file: "http://vidzi.tv/6c90fqha0k9i-4b4a926f75863405c12bfaeb331b331c.m3u8?embed=",
    [1] => http://vidzi.tv/6c90fqha0k9i-4b4a926f75863405c12bfaeb331b331c.m3u8?embed=
)
```

From above preg_match i get first

`file: "http://vidzi.tv/6c90fqha0k9i-4b4a926f75863405c12bfaeb331b331c.m3u8?embed="`

but i want to get this

```
file: "http://77.81.98.55/gzuqiu4h342qedz7nknr5h3sli74im5vv7f2ae7z2pxjxhqnqxk4625rsdpq/v.mp4"
```

help me thanks

Comment: Try using `(file: \"http:\/\/\d{2}.*?")`

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` and take the 2nd match from resulting array

Comment: The data, assigned to variable $string, looks like it ought to be json - is it?

Comment: if it is json then why complicate things and use a regex? why not simply json_decode the data and extract the required "file" directly?

Comment: Appears to be invalid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be broken `JSON` string you can use this regex:

```
preg_match_all('/file:\h*"([^"]*)"/i', $string, $m);

print_r($m[1][1]);
//=> http://77.81.98.55/gzuqiu4h342qedz7nknr5h3sli74im5vv7f2ae7z2pxjxhqnqxk4625rsdpq/v.mp4
```